# Is it possible to map multiple DTO objects to a single ViewModel using Automapper?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, automapper

I was wondering if it is possible to map multiple DTO objects to a single ViewModel object using Automapper?

Essentially, I have multiple DTO objects and would like to display information from each on a single screen in ASP.NET MVC 2.0. To do so I would like to flatten the DTO objects (or parts of them...) into the Viewmodel and pass said viewmodel to the view. If I had one DTO this would be easy, but I've never seen it being done with multiple. Obviously there are a number of roundabout ways to do this (outside of automapper), but this is the approach that I would like to take if possible.

Comment: you can with the ValueInjecter http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/documentation

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could create a composite DTO that holds two or more DTO objects and map the composite DTO to the output view model.

Comment: This is what we've done, and I found it works best.  That composite presentation object then tends to start containing behavior etc. relating to the composite objects.

Comment: I started going down that route but then came to the realization that if have to manually map to a composite object before I can Map<>(), then what is this extra step affording me? Following this approach, you ensure that all your object mappings are managed via AutoMapper, but then live with the exception of manual mappings to composites. I'm not completely opposed to the idea, just sayin...

Comment: Agree. The solution just posted by Gordon Nongkynrih looks much more elegant to me.

Answer (score 14):

Check for following link regarding your query

https://web.archive.org/web/20130417004510/http://consultingblogs.emc.com/owainwragg/archive/2010/12/22/automapper-mapping-from-multiple-objects.aspx

Comment: Although very late in this thread ;-), thank you very much for this link. I am just starting with AutoMapper and would have run into this problem very soon! Upvote! :-)

Comment: Thank you. I knew its quite late in the thread but having faced the same problem recently. I realize its never to late to update even old thread :)

Answer (score 9):

If you have 2 DTO classes and 1 flattened view model:

```
public class Dto1
{
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
}
public class Dto2
{
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
}
public class FlattenedViewModel
{
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
}
```

And you create mappings for both DTOs to view model:

```
CreateMap<Dto1, FlattenedViewModel>();
CreateMap<Dto2, FlattenedViewModel>();
```

You can map 1st DTO to the model and then just "append" 2nd DTO:

```
var dto1 = new Dto1 { Property1 = "Value1"; }
var dto2 = new Dto2 { Property2 = "Value2"; }

var model = Mapper.Map<FlattenedViewModel>(dto1); // map dto1 properties
Mapper.Map(dto2, model); // append dto2 properties
```

Comment: var model = Mapper.Map<FlattenedViewModel>(dto1); 
Mapper.Map(dto2, model); 
------------------------------------
Where this part of the code goes to? Is it in controller or service? If its service then is it Service1 or Service2?

Comment: @Ayyappa: In simple cases, this code is usually in the controller, but it can be extracted elsewhere. Depends on the complexity of your code and structure of your services.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So if the FlattenedViewModel is referenced from multiple controllers, its best to include at service layer. Right?

Comment: @Ayyappa: Sure you can wrap it in re-usable method. Is it method of a "service", it's opinionated question. If you have separate project only for service(s) loading `dto`s from database, then I would not make that project having dependency on MVC's `FlattenedViewModel`. Rather keep that code in MVC project.

Comment: Makes sense! Thanks a lot for your answers :)

Answer (score 4):

You can add a Map override extension method off IMappingEngine that takes a params array.  Something like:

```
public static class AutoMapperExtensions
{
    public static T Map<T>(this IMappingEngine engine, params object[] sources) where T : class
    {
        if (sources == null || sources.Length == 0)
            return default(T);

        var destinationType = typeof (T);
        var result = engine.Map(sources[0], sources[0].GetType(), destinationType) as T;
        for (int i = 1; i < sources.Length; i++)
        {
            engine.Map(sources[i], result, sources[i].GetType(), destinationType);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

You could then call it like this:

```
var result = Mapper.Engine.Map<MyViewModel>(dto1, dto2, dto3);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the information from the expired link in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8923063/2005596

When using AutoMapper (http://automapper.codeplex.com ) I often have a scenario where I need to map several entities into one entity. Commonly this occurs when mapping from a number domain entities into a single view model (ASP.NET MVC). Unfortunately the AutoMapper API does not expose functionality to map several entities into one entity; however it is relatively simple to create some helper method to do this. Below I will illustrate the approach that I have taken.

In this example I have the following entities in my domain model

```
public class Person

{

    public int Id { get; set; }



    public string Firstname { get; set; }



    public string Surname { get; set; }

}



public class Address

{

    public int Id { get; set; }



    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }



    public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }



    public string Country { get; set; }

}



public class Comment

{

    public string Text { get; set; }



    public DateTime Created { get; set; }

}
```

In addition to this I have a requirement to render the person details the person’s address and any related comment on a single page (using ASP.NET MVC). To implement this I have created the view model shown below, which includes data from all three of the domain entities shown above

```
public class PersonViewModel

{

    public int Id { get; set; }



    [DisplayName("Firstname")]

    public string Firstname { get; set; }



    [DisplayName("Surname")]

    public string Surname { get; set; }



    [DisplayName("Address Line 1")]

    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }



    [DisplayName("Address Line 2")]

    public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }



    [DisplayName("Country Of Residence")]

    public string Country { get; set; }



    [DisplayName("Admin Comment")]

    public string Comment { get; set; }



}
```

In the controller action method I make three separate calls into the domain layer to retrieve the required entities but this still leaves the issue that I need to map several source entities onto a single destination entity. To perform this mapping I created a helper class which encapsulates AutoMapper and exposes functionality which enables the mapping of several source objects onto one destination object. This class is shown below

```
public static class EntityMapper

{

    public static T Map<T>(params object[] sources) where T : class

    {

        if (!sources.Any())

        {

            return default(T);

        }



        var initialSource = sources[0];



        var mappingResult = Map<T>(initialSource);



        // Now map the remaining source objects

        if (sources.Count() > 1)

        {

            Map(mappingResult, sources.Skip(1).ToArray());

        }



        return mappingResult;

    }



    private static void Map(object destination, params object[] sources)

    {

        if (!sources.Any())

        {

            return;

        }



        var destinationType = destination.GetType();



        foreach (var source in sources)

        {

            var sourceType = source.GetType();

            Mapper.Map(source, destination, sourceType, destinationType);

        }

    }



    private static T Map<T>(object source) where T : class

    {

        var destinationType = typeof(T);

        var sourceType = source.GetType();



        var mappingResult = Mapper.Map(source, sourceType, destinationType);



        return mappingResult as T;

    }

}
```

To map several source objects onto one destination I have made use of the functionality provided by AutoMapper which allows you to perform a mapping between a source object and a destination object that already exists.

Finally below is the code from the controller that retrieves the three entities and performs the mapping onto a single view model

```
    public ActionResult Index()

    {



        // Retrieve the person, address and comment entities and

        // map them on to a person view model entity

        var personId = 23;



        var person = _personTasks.GetPerson(personId);

        var address = _personTasks.GetAddress(personId);

        var comment = _personTasks.GetComment(personId);



        var personViewModel = EntityMapper.Map<PersonViewModel>(person, address, comment);



        return this.View(personViewModel);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just worked this out myself and have a great solution. It is most likely that your two views are actually related somehow in your system (especially if you are using Entity Framework). Check your models and you should see something which displays the relationship, if you don't then just add it. (The `virtual`)

Your models

```
    public class Dto1
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string Property2 { get; set; }
        public string Property3 { get; set; }
        public string Property4 { get; set; }
        public string Property5 { get; set; }

        public virtual Dto2 dto2{ get; set; }

    }

    public class Dto2
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string PropertyB { get; set; }
        public string PropertyC { get; set; }
        public string PropertyD { get; set; }
        public string PropertyE { get; set; }
    }
```

Your ViewModels

```
    public class Dto1ViewModel
    {
        public string Property1 { get; set; }
        public string Property2 { get; set; }

        public virtual Dto2VMForDto1 dto2{ get; set; }
    }

//Special ViewModel just for sliding into the above
    public class Dto2VMForDto1 
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string PropertyB { get; set; }
        public string PropertyC { get; set; }
    }
```

Automapper looks like this:

```
        cfg.CreateMap< Dto1, Dto1ViewModel>();
        cfg.CreateMap< Dto2, Dto2VMForDto1 >();
```

I'm assuming you are getting your data with LinQ:

```
Dto1ViewModel thePageVM = (from entry in context.Dto1 where...).ProjectTo<Dto1ViewModel>();
```

Viola, everything will work. In your view just access by using `model.dto2.PropertyB`