# AutoMapper - Convert two entity objects to a single DTO

Tags: entity-framework, automapper

I have two EntityFramework models that I want to combine into a single DTO. Is there a way to do this? There are a couple ideas in the following question, but you would either have to create a composite model, or lose the ability to call Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid to verify all of the properties will be set.

[Is it possible to map multiple DTO objects to a single ViewModel using Automapper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127786/is-it-possible-to-map-multiple-dto-objects-to-a-)
single-viewmodel-using-automappe

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view, It is highly recommanded to create a composite type for merging entities. Entities are part of your Business logic or your Domain logic (depending on your architecture), whereas DTO are part of Presentation logic or Transport layer. You can create an explicit mapping that can be easily tested ; automatic mapping (create maps without options) is good for testing only. If you are using a DTO, then you will  probably use it somewhere : in WCF ? as a ViewModel ?

Visual Studio and .Net Framework can manage many files and you have not to sacrifice testability or simplicity (do you know "Technical Debt"?)

Note : The role of Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid is to validate all mapping, generated by automatic or explicit mapping. I suggest you call this every time.

Comment: The same question would still apply if I were to convert from two entity models to a composite model. Maybe I should have stated it in a more general way. I was hoping that there would be a more automated way of accomplishing this where I wouldn't have to go change the mapping every time I add a new property.

Comment: Not understood you first sentence. You can use automatic mapping but you will loose control over mapped properties. Could you specify why you want to convert two entity objects to a single DTO.